# Problem with Udemy tutorial: getting 'Error while evaluating UIControl Callback.'

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I am going through the Udemy course "Learn image processing and GUIs while having fun in MATLAB". I'm trying to create the GUI to plot lines of random numbers. I'm troubleshooting this bit of code:

`% --- Executes on button press in MakeThePlot.

function MakeThePlot_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

numCol = str2double( get(handles.numLines,'string') );

disp('A')

There is a dot next to the last line indicating (I guess) that I'm only working with the MakeThePlot function. If I do NOT have the line beginning with "numCol" in the file, it runs perfectly, displaying A in the console every time I hit the "MakeThePlot' button in the GUI. Add in the one line, and it throws the error I give in the title. AFAIK I'm following the instructor's steps exactly. What am I doing wrong? THanks in advance.

I'm not sure what to add to what I gave above. I tried putting in only one line of the instructor's code in the function to keep it simple. I expected it to do nothing but display 'A' in the console.